# Print component colours from a named colour?

Tags: color

How can I print component colours as percentages for a previously defined colour? In this case I only care about CMYK colours.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{SomeColour}{cmyk}{0.8,0.6,0.4,0.2}
\newcommand{\printcomponents}[1]{
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    Composite & \textcolor{#1}{#1} \\
    Cyan & 80 \\ % <- Return cyan component as percentage
    Magenta & 60 \\ % <- Return magenta component as percentage
    Yellow & 40 \\ % <- Return yellow component as percentage
    Black & 20 \\ % <- Return black component as percentage
  \end{tabular}
}
\begin{document}
\printcomponents{SomeColour}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `xcolor` package provides `\extractcolorspecs` in order to retrieve the color model and the color specification:

```
  \extractcolorspecs{#1}{\colmodel}{\colspec}
```

stores the model to `\colmodel` and the colors to`\colspec`, which is a comma separated list.

In order to process the list I used `expl3` features.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{SomeColour}{cmyk}{0.8,0.6,0.4,0.2}


\definecolor{OtherColour}{cmyk}{0.4,0.66,0.45,0.1}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \extractcontent#1#2 {%
  \clist_set:Nx \l_tmpa_clist {#1}% Store the list
  \fp_eval:n { 100 * \clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {#2}} % use the list item #2 and multiply it with 100 
}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\newcommand{\printcomponents}[1]{%
  \extractcolorspecs{#1}{\colmodel}{\colspec}
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    Composite & \textcolor{#1}{#1} \\
    Cyan & \extractcontent{\colspec}{1} \\ % <- Return cyan component as percentage
    Magenta & \extractcontent{\colspec}{2} \\ % <- Return magenta component as percentage
    Yellow & \extractcontent{\colspec}{3} \\ % <- Return yellow component as percentage
    Black & \extractcontent{\colspec}{4} \\ % <- Return black component as percentage
  \end{tabular}
}
\begin{document}
\printcomponents{SomeColour}

\printcomponents{OtherColour}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'll try to find a method with `l3colors` later on